# app crashes when i click on a image

Tags: android

I had 4 buttons which contains different images,

I want to open images in gridview when i click on a image in emulator it should display the image in a new layout(its working fine in 1st adaper class), but when i open images on 2nd button the images in the emulator its shows the images in adapter class2  but when i click on a image it shows the image in 1st adapter class

ImageActivity.java

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.image_selection);
            Button a,b,c,d;

            b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
           b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, screen2.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
           } 
         }
```

screen2.java

```
public class screen2 extends Activity{
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen2);   

            GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter2(this));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity1.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
     }
    }
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public Integer[] images = {
         R.drawable.baby1, R.drawable.baby2,
         R.drawable.baby3,R.drawable.baby4,
    };
    public ImageAdapter2(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(60, 60));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return imageView;
    }
```

}

FullImageActivity.java

```
    public class FullImageActivity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter2 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter2(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.images[position]);      
    }
}
```

logcat is

```
    07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{abhinai.image/abhinai.image.FullImageActivity3}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at abhinai.image.FullImageActivity3.onCreate(FullImageActivity3.java:19)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-19 15:24:24.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1709):     ... 11 more
```

can anyone help me

Comment: Inside your `ImageAcivity` you have `Intent i = new Intent(ImageActivity.this, screen1.class);`. Do you have a class by the name of `screen1.java`' which is not shown here?

Comment: You should add Stacktrace of the crash °°flies away°°

Comment: its not showing any error in logcat

Comment: @shobhit puri sorry i miss typed screen1 there its screen2.java

Comment: @Abhinai a crash means you will see some exceptions/errors in logcat.post the same.

Comment: @raghunandan logcat added, please check this once

Comment: @Abhinai a crash means you will see some excpetions in logcat. this is not what is required. run it again and then post the logcat. R u getting Unfortunately app stopped?. Also application is doing too much work means you will have to do some operation's on a background thread.

Comment: noo the app doesnt crash now but i am getting the same images in imagesadapter1.java when i click on a image

Comment: Could it be because you're hardcoding FullImageActivity1.class into your intent?  Or is that intended?

Comment: The Error is on line 19 of FullImageActivity3, which you have not posted here

Comment: @jameo its same as fullimageactivity2 instead of 2 its 3

Comment: Thanks for all for replying me i got this error rectified i havent mentioned the layout in 2nd screen now i did